# Replace 'value' with 'data-filter' in example

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys, 
here is an example of dependent select options.

```js
$('#city').change(function() {
  $('#street option').hide();
  $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
  // add this code to select 1'st of streets automaticaly 
  // when city changed
  if ($('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length) {
    $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
  }
  // in case if there's no corresponding street: 
  // reset select element
  else {
    $('#street').val('');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0">Select City</option>
  <option value="1">Manchester</option>
  <option value="2">Leicester</option>
  <option value="3">Londra</option>
</select>

<select id="street" name="street">
  <option value="0">Select Street</option>
  <option value="1">Street 1</option>
  <option value="1">Street 2</option>
  <option value="1">Street 3</option>
  <option value="2">Street 4</option>
  <option value="2">Street 5</option>
  <option value="2">Street 6</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 7</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 8</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 9</option>
</select>
```

Everything is fine with, but in need to replace value-based filtering with data attributes based, like so:

```
<option value="1">Street 1</option>  =>  <option data-filter="1" value="">Street 1</option>
```

Your help is a highly appreciated.

Comment: Why? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you wish?
To use `data-filter` instead of `value`?

Ok, the twist here is that you have to look for the selected `option`... Since the value isn't tied to the `select` anymore. That's all.

```js
$('#city').change(function() {

  var cityFilter = $(this).find("option:selected").data("filter");
  
  $('#street option').hide();
  $('#street option[data-filter="' + cityFilter + '"]').show();
  // add this code to select 1'st of streets automaticaly 
  // when city changed
  if ($('#street option[data-filter="' + cityFilter + '"]').length) {
    $('#street option[data-filter="' + cityFilter + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
  }
  // in case if there's no corresponding street: 
  // reset select element
  else {
    $('#street').val('');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="" data-filter="0">Select City</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1">Manchester</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="2">Leicester</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="3">Londra</option>
</select>

<select id="street" name="street">
  <option value="" data-filter="0">Select Street</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1">Street 1</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1">Street 2</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1">Street 3</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="2">Street 4</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="2">Street 5</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="2">Street 6</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1200">Street 7</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1200">Street 8</option>
  <option value="" data-filter="1200">Street 9</option>
</select>
```

I also "reduced" the amount of jQuery lookups... using the `cityFilter` variable.

Feel free for questions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to use

```
$(this).find(":selected").attr('data-filter')
```

and

```
$(this).find(":selected").attr('data-filter') + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
```

So instead of targeting the 'value' attribute you switch to the 'data-attributeName'.

Update: Here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/Lsad/pen/aXNRjj) based on your pen.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it here  - https://codepen.io/muezza/pen/OdNoOB

It doesn't work for some reason,

Comment: @StanislavBourakov here's working example from your pen https://codepen.io/Lsad/pen/aXNRjj